# Download file from sharepoint url using VBA (urlmon.dll) not working. Is there any alternative for latest version of Office 365?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I am using in VBA to download file from sharepoint link. I am passing url and filename and I can see the downloaded file on destination drive, but it is not opening up as if it is not downloaded at all and code created a dummy file with same extension and name.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
```

Please help and advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the correct data type for `lpfnCB`:

```vb
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "Urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) _
        As Long
```